# Making dropdown css menu full height of the media browser on

Tags: html, css

I have created a full responsive CSS menu that becomes a drop-down at smaller browser sizes.

the drop-down at smaller screen sizes is behaving as expected but what I would like to do is force the drop-down elements to occupy the full height and width of the window without changing the size of the page (I've achieved full width but not full height).  In other words, I want the menu to occupy the full height of the window and lay on top of everything but the button (so it can be collapsed again obviously.

I've tried altering a number of attributes but at the moment I'm not sure if this is possible this way or not.  Does anyone have thoughts on how to do this?

[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/warmonger0/fhkc6t89/1/)

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

a {
  color: #000;
}

/* pagenav */

.pagenav {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.pagenav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.pagenav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagenav li a:hover,
.pagenav .nav-right-btn:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

/* nav-right */

.pagenav .nav-right {
  clear: both;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}

/* nav-right icon */

.pagenav .nav-right-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  padding: 28px 20px;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
}

.pagenav .nav-right-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.pagenav .nav-right-icon .navicon:before,
.pagenav .nav-right-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.pagenav .nav-right-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.pagenav .nav-right-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* nav-right btn */

.pagenav .nav-right-btn {
  display: none;
}

.pagenav .nav-right-btn:checked ~ .nav-right {
  max-height: 240px;
}

.pagenav .nav-right-btn:checked ~ .nav-right-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.pagenav .nav-right-btn:checked ~ .nav-right-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.pagenav .nav-right-btn:checked ~ .nav-right-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.pagenav .nav-right-btn:checked ~ .nav-right-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.pagenav .nav-right-btn:checked ~ .nav-right-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .pagenav li {
    float: left;
  }
  .pagenav li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .pagenav .nav-right {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
  .pagenav .nav-right-icon {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

      <link href="cover4.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">


  </head>
  <body>

<header class="pagenav">

  <input class="nav-right-btn" type="checkbox" id="nav-right-btn" />
  <label class="nav-right-icon" for="nav-right-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="nav-right">
    <li><a href="#reel">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bio">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Link3</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** - animate the menu to `height: calc(100vh - $nav-height)` on click.

I believe what you're looking for is **vh and vw units**, viewport width and viewport height. They work like percentages, but instead of being relative to the parent container (like setting `width: 100%`) they are relative to the viewport. So, for example, `width: 100vw` would mean 100% of the **viewport** width, **not** its parent container.

These units have very good support across all current browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

If you want the dropdown elements to also take up the whole height of the page, you could use Flexbox to achieve that. Wrap the list elements in a `display: flex` container and play around with the `justify-content` and `align-items` attribute (probably using the `space-around` property) so that the items automatically spread out. Here's a brilliant guide on the specifics of Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**Edit**: Thanks to [Mark E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362366/mark-e) for providing a working fiddle. Including here a modified version that uses the `display: flex` property to spread out the elements across the whole height of the page: https://jsfiddle.net/od5g8v4a/14/. It doesn't seem to break the desktop version of the menu. I included comments to show what has been modified.

Note that technically the height shouldn't be animated to `100vh` exactly - it should be `100vh - $navbar-height`. You might want to [use the `calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function to achieve this.

Comment: i'd be interested in seeing this modified fiddle.  The whole code including animation is being done with css which is included.

Comment: testing the above to see if it works too.  the trouble is I only want this to happen at the smaller browser size so if it breaks things at the larger browser size, then this wouldn't be a good solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

What about using an `onclick` javascript function for the button that gets the window size as a variable. Then you can use an if then statement to determine if you want to employ Daniel H.'s solution. Something like this-

```
<script>
    function getWindowSizeOnclick() {
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        if (h > [however high you need it to be]) {
          document.getElementByID("menuInQuestion").style.height = "100vh";
        }
     }
    function sizeOnWindowResize() {
          document.getElementByID("menuInQuestion").style.height = "original-size"
     }
</script>
```

put that the bottom of the page before the closing `</body>` tag then in the opening tag of your button put `onclick="getWindowSizeOnClick()"` Then put this in the opening body tag `onresize="sizeOnWindowResize()"`

Think that would do the trick?

Comment: So, i've tried using JS for this before and it has some interesting behaviors like, the inability to re-display items at different media sizes if you use them to manipulate their properties.  I.e. if you click the menu, implementing the 100vh property on the element you're trying to style, it doesn't reset this property when media queries are called again on window resize.

Comment: You can call a function to reset the property using onresize in that case. Edited the answer to reflect that.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

Comment: Why in the heck did someone down vote this answer? Is there something wrong with it?